# How to rename/change the comment labels in WordPress backend?

Tags: comments

[image: The image is as given.]
The screenshot shows what to change.

Comment: Please edit your question with written text about what you are asking. If you want to add an image, insert it here, rather than just link it. Thanks. :)

Comment: I am new here thank you for your advice. I've posted the question correctly now.